# Why SQL Server stored procedure runs in live database but not in local pc?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2000

I have created a stored procedure :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_PettyCash_GetSingleUserInfo 
(
    @MaerskID varchar(50)  
)
AS
BEGIN  
    SELECT ISNULL(MaerskID,'') AS UniqueID, ISNULL(FirstName,'') AS FirstName, ISNULL(MiddleName,'') AS MiddleName, ISNULL(LastName,'') AS LastName, ISNULL(EmployeeType,'') AS EmployeeType
    FROM Users a 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t_PettyCash_EmployeeInfo b ON a.MaerskID = b.UniqueID
    WHERE a.MaerskID = @MaerskID 
END 
GO
```

And it works fine in my live database server. To make some modification, I BACKUP my database and restore it in my local pc. The problem is, when I run my web app from local pc, it gives the exception,

> Could not find stored procedure 'usp_PettyCash_GetSingleUserInfo'

I gave my pc's database user admin rights but still it gives the error. I am not sure what actually the problem is. I don't think the problem is in my code because, when I connect to my live database, everything is FINE. Please help. Of course, I first tested the stored procedure in local pc before going for live DB. that time everything works fine, but now its not.

I am using SQL Server 2000 Enterprise Edition and VS2005 ASP.Net & C# 2.0.

Comment: it's either not there, or it's permissions, or you are pointing to wrong DB.

Comment: ... or another default schema. Alter your create to `CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_...` and inlude `dbo.`into your call to the procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this issue.

1.)Drop Existing SP.

2.)Create new SP.

Now you will get the result.I also faced that problem but this trick works for me.One this more please check the SQL server on both end.

Hope it helps

Comment: I was hoping to get an alternate way rather dropping and creating SPs. I already did that to solve the matter. I wish there is a more better solution to this problem. However, I will give you an up vote.

Comment: While creating the store procedure please be careful the database selected in the database

Comment: OK,make one test create another test SP with same query but with different name call this SP.